# Celluloid actors parallel work slow?

Tags: ruby, parallel-programming, actor-model, multi-core, multiprocessing

I'm new to actors and just playing around in ruby using Celluloid. I have this code below

```
module Enumerable
  # Simple parallel map using Celluloid::Futures
  def pmap(&block)
    futures = map { |elem| Celluloid::Future.new(elem, &block) }
    futures.map(&:value)
  end
end

p Benchmark.measure{
 100_000.times.pmap { |n| n * 2 }
}

p Benchmark.measure{
 100_000.times.map { |n| n * 2 }
}
```

the time for pmap: 13.98 s

the time for map:  0.021 s

Why is the celluloid implementation so much slower? Am I using it wrong or is celluloid inherently much slower even though it is multi-core/parallel computing (I'm using Jruby so no GIL)? Is celluloid just optimal because of multiple thread == good encapsulation, that there is never a performance boost for smaller computations? Is there is, is there any example of where Celluloid actually performs faster?

Answer (score 1):

Because your unit of work has a very fast execution time:

```
|n| n * 2
```

It is likely that the execution overhead of the futures is much greater than the total execution time of your units of work.  After all, the `pmap` version requires the creation ten thousand `Celluloid::Future` objects.  That has to take some time.

If your unit of work took a bit longer to execute, I think you would see markedly different results.

Comment: What kind of work would be suitable to show off if celluloid parallelism actually does something for performance? I've tried just doing ridiculous multiplications but celluloid always performs worse.

Comment: I suspect that your workload would have to be at least an order of magnitude, and maybe several orders of magnitude, larger than the overhead imposed by Celluloid.  That probably wouldn't take much, but it would take more than routine math problems, which typically execute very quickly.  As an example, if your load were 10 times the load of creating a Future, your overhead would still be 10 percent of the computation.  Making objects is a non-trivial load.

Comment: @Grimbox: a really stupid test would be to add a 1 second `sleep` to your block. Theoretically, the parallel version should perform all those sleeps in parallel and thus only take 1 second, whereas the serial version takes 100000 seconds, i.e. 28 hours. Well, okay, maybe it's a good idea to start with a lower value :-D